# TensorFlow Probability GLM tfp.glm for Multi-Class Classification

Tags: tensorflow, glm, lasso-regression, tensorflow-probability

In the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Generalized_Linear_Models#with_l1_regularization) the `model` specified for logistic (binary) regression is `tfp.glm.Bernoulli()`; how do we fit a model on a target with three or more classes in `tfp.glm`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

TFP GLM doesn't currently support multiclass models. If this would be useful to you, please create a Github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues